# R function to generate and save RMarkdown pdf and iterate over multiple CSVs in folder

Tags: r, r-markdown, data-wrangling

I have many CSV files with time series data from environmental sensors. All of them have columns with the same names/order, and they look like this:

```
# create time series columns
datetime <- as.POSIXct(c("2022-01-14 17:00:00 UTC", "2022-01-14 17:15:00 UTC", "2022-01-14 17:30:00 UTC", "2022-01-14 17:45:00 UTC", "2022-01-14 18:00:00 UTC"))
siteID <- rep("04M09_2", 10)
tempC <- c(6.9783360, 6.5733036, 5.3476500, 4.1025504, 3.2613720, 
           2.4101928, 1.6562436, 1.2212088, 1.0028580, 0.8928492)
SpC <- rep(0, 10)
wetdry <- rep("dry", 10)
lat <- rep(39.07982, 10)
long <- rep(-96.5816, 10)
field_SpC <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 20)

# make data frame
sensor_04M09 <- data.frame(datetime, siteID, tempC, SpC, wetdry, lat, long, field_SpC)
```

I would like to write an R function that I could iterate over an entire folder of CSV data from these sensors (one CSV file per sensor) to produce and save a pdf of this document for each sensor. Here is what I want the Markdown to look like. (Note: the csv that I show as being read in at first is like the one I created for this example above)

```
---
title: "04M09_2 STIC Summary"
author: "Me"
date: '2022-09-08'
output: pdf_document
---
```

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

Bring in processed STIC data frame

```
library(tidyverse)
sensor_04M09 <- read_csv("sensor_04M09.csv")

head(sensor_04M09)
```

Time series of SpC colored by wet/dry designation (red dot represents field SpC measurement)

```
ggplot(Sensor_04M09, aes(x = datetime, y = SpC, color = wetdry, group = 1)) + 
  geom_path(size = 0.7) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = datetime, y = field_SpC), size = 3, color = "red") +
   theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(colour = "black", size = 1)) + 
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 14))
```

Time series of Temperature (C) recorded by sensor

```
ggplot(Sensor_04M09, aes(x = datetime, y = tempC)) + 
  geom_path() + 
  geom_smooth(color = "steelblue", se = FALSE) +
   theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(colour = "black", size = 1)) + 
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 14))
```

Map of Sensor location

```
library(Rcpp)
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(rasterVis)
library(sf)

# Bring in stream line shape files
konza_streams <- st_read("GIS210/GIS210.shp")

sensor_location <- st_as_sf(STIC_KNZ_04M09_00_LS,
                                coords = c("long", "lat"), 
                                crs = 4326)

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = konza_streams) + 
  geom_sf(data = sensor_location, size = 3, color = "red") +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(colour = "black", size = 1)) + 
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 9),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 12)) +
  xlab("Longitude") + 
  ylab("Latitude") + 
  coord_sf(xlim = c(708000.9  , 710500.3 ), ylim = c(4327200.8  , 4330000.0 ), expand = FALSE)
```

The purpose of creating and saving these pdf markdown docs for each CSV file in the folder is for a visual QAQC check of the data from each sensor.

Comment: Build an Rmarkdown doc with a parameter for the data file to read in. Then, render that doc a bunch of times, once for each CSV file (perhaps use list.files() to get a vector of the CSV filenames, then loop over a knitr::render() function using those filenames). See this page for how to use parameters in rmarkdown: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-6.html (edit: I guess this can be an answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RMarkdown documents allow parameters, which you can set while rendering the document to change some aspects of how it runs. See [this page](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-6.html) for additional detail on using parameters.

In your RMarkdown document, set up your YAML to accept the parameter:

```
---
title: "04M09_2 STIC Summary"
author: "Me"
date: '2022-09-08'
output: pdf_document
params:
    datafile: "sensor.csv"
---
```

Then, in the code, use that parameter to select the data file of interest, and run all your calculations/graphs:

```r
library(tidyverse)
sensor_04M09 <- read_csv(params$datafile)

# And then put all your graphing code, etc., using the sensor_04M09 dataset
# (or name it something more generic)
```

Now you have an RMarkdown doc that can be given a filename and will produce your range of graphs using the data from that file. Save that as `analysis_file.rmd` or something.

Finally, produce a script to loop over all the files you want it to run through. In a separate `.R` script:

```r
library(rmarkdown)
library(stringr)

# directory is the folder with all your data files in it
list_of_files = list.files('directory', '.csv')
for (f in list_of_files) {
    # Get the names of the sensors alone, for making filenames
    outputname = paste0('analysis_of_',str_sub(f, 1, nchar(f) - 4),'.pdf')
    # get the full filename of the data file
    full_file = paste0('directory/',f)
    render("analysis_file.rmd", output_file = outputname, params = list(datafile = full_file))
}
```

This will loop through all the files and render the document once for each.